# Как указать другое местоположение файла конфигурации?

Tags: jpa, java

Здравствуйте. Как в `JPA 2` указать другое местоположение файла конфигурации `persistence.xml` (по умолчанию, в папке `META-INF`) или указать в этом файле место, где доставать файлы с `persistence-unit`, где находится описание вида

```
<persistence-unit name="commonStorage">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>rct.gomel.drp.persistence.entities.commonstorage.CsDiagnosticResult</class>
    <class>rct.gomel.drp.persistence.entities.commonstorage.CsRegistrationCard</class>
    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                     value="jdbc:sqlserver://rct-server:1433;
                     databaseName=RCT_CommonStorage"/>  
... ... ... ...
```

Comment: Я хочу сделать jar, где будет интерфейс работы с БД, а все остальное, чтобы было в приложении, использующем этот jar. Т.е. некий модуль для использования в разных приложениях внутри предприятия.  
Другими словами, чтобы приложение имело только файл конфигурации и .jar файл с логикой работы с базой данных.

Comment: И т.к. я изучил только JPA на некий уровень, позволяющий его использовать, то не хотелось бы ради этого изучать что-то другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам это понадобилось? И куда вы хотите положить его? Может, проще при сборке положить его куда надо, чем городить огород? Насколько я знаю, можно класть либо в META-INF всего приложения, либо в META-INF внутри jar'а, положенного в lib внутри war'а.

Так сделайте конфигурацию такой, чтобы её содержимое можно было намертво забить в jar. Используйте в `persistence.xml` внешние `connection pool`'ы. Конфигурируйте их отдельно от приложения. Не прописывайте никакие хосты, порты, логины и тем более пароли в `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Одна проблема решилась, а как быть с бинами `@Entity`, которые должны будут реализовывать программы-пользователи?  
@cy6erGn0m, преобразуйте свои комментарии в ответ.

Comment: Никак. Пускай они и реализуют их. Главное, чтобы в момент пуска контекста соответствующие классы были видимы для контейнера.